# Not able to call a perl script from a shell script

Tags: perl

I am trying to call a perl script from a shell script and code looks like shown below...

shell script test_sh

```
#Call the script
test2.pl ${PARTITION_ID} ${VNG_USER} ${VNG_PASSWORD} ${VNG_INSTANCE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    OP1ExitStatus -6
fi
```

while execution getting below error message:

```
./test_sh[142]: test2.pl:  not found
Failed in test_sh
```

permission given to both files are 755.

But when i and calling test2.pl directly from the command line by passing all arguments it runs successfully.
I tried with below command as well :

```
#Call the script
perl test2.pl ${PARTITION_ID} ${VNG_USER} ${VNG_PASSWORD} ${VNG_INSTANCE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    OP1ExitStatus -6
fi
```

but it is also not working.
please let me know how to proceed in order to run it successfully.

Comment: So how is the second one "not working"?  Any error message?

Answer (score 3):

From the command line you're invoking `perl test2.pl` directly.  From the script you're assuming that (1) `test2.pl` is executable and (2) `.` is in `$PATH` somewhere.  I would use the direct `perl` invocation in the script, at least for now.

Comment: Alternatively: `./test2.pl` if the script has a shebang and has been `chmod +x`ed.

Comment: @Benôit: Indeed, although I usually only do that with scripts without extensions, considering the extension to be an indication that it's supposed to be fed directly to the appropriate interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

check your shebang, eg `#!/bin/bash`. you may also want to try using the full path of your Perl executable.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that the path to `perl` in the shebang line at the top of the Perl script is wrong (assuming that the file has execute permission for you).

Try using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script is unable to find your test2.pl. You need to give the full path of test2.pl in your shell script or ensure it is in your $PATH.